# What are the differences between conditional and proviso clauses?

Tags: subordinate-clause, conditions

In Keller's Learn to Read Latin:

> The conjunction dum, sometimes strengthened by the adverb modo, "only", may introduce a subordinate clause stating a provision under which the event of the main clause can occur. Such a clause is called a proviso clause.

In a conditional sentence, the conditional clause

> states the condition that must occur in order for the main clause to occur.

and is introduced by si or nisi.

My questions are:

- What are the differences between conditional and proviso clauses? How different are they in terms of logic?
- Can a conjunction that introduces one be used for introducing the other?

Thanks.

Comment: Latin tutorial(YouTube)has a video about that.

Comment: could you summarize it here? Thanks

Comment: My grammar basically says(about the conjunctions Dum/dummodo and modo)hat the  proviso clause introduces a conditional clause of final value. I didn't understand at all, but, woud be a conditional that has a meaning of a final clause. It's the first time i hear abou that.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose they're pretty similar: *dum* here means 'provided that'/'so long as'; *si* just means 'if'. They might sometimes be interchangeable, but not always: imagine Caligula saying *oderint si metuunt*? [If you're not familiar - his catchphrase was *oderint dum metuant* - 'let them hate me so long as they fear me'.]

Bear in mind *dum* here takes *ne* as a negative.